# iis 7.5 (windows 7) and 2nd (second) iis 5 (xp pro)

Tags: windows-xp, iis-7.5, windows-7, iis

i have 2 computers.
both were xp pro, so when i remote the main one i could have my 2 iis work like this:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx/website - this is from the pc
http://xx.xx.xx.xx/laptop/website - this is from the laptop
```

now i have iis 7.5 on my pc so having virtual directory on my pc to the laptop is not working. it is not working from inside or outside.
i get error

***HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.***

i don't have web.config files there - so i don't know what is the reason

what can i do so i can access both of the computers?

Comment: when changed the path from maped drive b:\websites\ to \\xx.xx.xx.xx\websites

it is working but then i get error 500

Comment: You'd better edit your post adding Update1, Update2. Where have you map-drived your website. What happened with Windows XP? Where is your IIS7.5? Are you accessing mapped drives from the same user? Is it on th local network? Tell a little more about configurations, contexts, changes, OSes, network, etc.! The situation is currently incomprehensible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this solution:
http://www.winservermart.com/Howto/HTTP_Error_500_19_IIS_7.aspx

However, when I looked for other solutions, I found out that the issue could be caused by several sources so if none of the afore-mentioned solutions help you, can you please edit your question and paste the error page's content?

Good luck!
Borislav

Answer (score -2):

> i don't have web.config files there -
>   so i don't know what is the reason

If you do not have web.config files, then machine.config is used

> what can i do so i can access both of
>   the computers?

I would advise to explicitly create web.config files according to your needs.
For this, first formulate what you need.
Second, if you cannot cope alone, then let others to help you